# Eloquent Model parent and child relationship

Tags: laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have two tables Questions and QuestionBank.

I created a two models Questions and QuestionBank.

Primary key : Questions table : (QuestionID), QuestionBank table : (QuestionBankID).

Foreign key : Questions.QuestionBankID = QuestionBank.QuestionBankID

Question Model:

```
public function QuestionBank() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\QuestionBank'); // this matches the Eloquent model
}
```

QuestionBank Model:

```
public function Questions() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questions'); // this matches the Eloquent model
}
```

In my controller i wrote a code:

return Questions::with('QuestionBank')->get();

Run the Router:

i got the null value pair for question_bank:null

My output:

```
[{"QuestionTitle":"OSCE","question_bank":null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use non-standard column names, you have to specify them:

```
public function QuestionBank() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\QuestionBank', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionBankID');
}
```

In the opposite direction it's a `HasMany` relationship:

```
public function Questions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Questions', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionBankID');
}
```

Add this to your `Question` model to adjust the response:

```
protected $appends = ['QuestionBankName'];

public function getQuestionBankNameAttribute() {
    return $this->QuestionBank->QuestionBank;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My response is [{"QuestionTitle":"OSCE","question_bank":{"QuestionBank":"Practice Bank"}}]. But i need [{"QuestionTitle":"OSCE","QuestionBank"::"Practice Bank"}]

Comment: Where does the name `question_bank` come from? Is it somewhere in your `Question` model?

Comment: protected $visible = ["QuestionTitle","QuestionBank"];

Comment: I'm wondering about the underscore, is that somewhere in the model?

Comment: class Questionbank extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ["QuestionBank"];

    protected $table = "QuestionBank";

    protected $dates = [];
    protected $primaryKey = "QuestionBankID";

    protected $visible = ["QuestionBank"];

    public static $rules = [
        // Validation rules
    ];

    public function Questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questions', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionBankID');
    }

    // Relationships

}

Comment: class Questions extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ["QuestionTitle"];

    protected $dates = [];

    protected $primaryKey = "QuestionID";
    protected $foreignKey = "QuestionBankID";

    public static $rules = [
        // Validation rules
    ];
    protected $visible = ["QuestionTitle","QuestionBank"];
    // Relationships

   public function QuestionBank() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\QuestionBank', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionBankID');
    }

}

Comment: I can't explain the underscore. But I included a way to add the question bank's name to the response, take a look at my answer.

Comment: Hi i append the question model $append and member function, in my controller i invoke the method return Questions::with('QuestionBank')->get(); i got the response [{"QuestionTitle":"OSCE","question_bank":{"QuestionBank":"Practice Bank"}}]. Another way return Questions::with('QuestionBank')->getQuestionBankNameAttribute()->get(); I got error Bad method calling exceptions.

Comment: Did you use `$append` or `$appends`?

Comment: Same issue occur i try the  $append / $appends.
Controll : return Questions::with('QuestionBank')->getQuestionBankNameAttribute()->get();
I got the Method exception error.

Comment: You don't have to (and can't) call `->getQuestionBankNameAttribute()` like that. When the result is converted to JSON it should automatically use `$appends` to add custom data (e.g. `QuestionBankName`).